# Cannot access nested dictionary element python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I wanna increment element(int) in nested dictionary:

```
letters[c]['rep'] += 1
```

where c is a string that is a key. For example, if c is 'a', then it should do this:

```
letters['a']['rep'] += 1
```

but it increments all 'rep' for all the c in dictionary. How to fix this? Thanks!

edit1:
Letters are initilized this way:

```
def initilize_dict():
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        letters[letter] = data
```

where data is:

```
data = {'rep': 0,
    'next': [],
    'freq': 0,
    'dev': 0}
```

empty dict letters looks like this:

```
{'a': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'b': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'c': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'd': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'e': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'f': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'g': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'h': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'i': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'j': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'k': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'l': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'm': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'n': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'o': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'p': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'q': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'r': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 's': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 't': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'u': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'v': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'w': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'x': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'y': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0},
 'z': {'dev': 0, 'freq': 0, 'next': [], 'rep': 0}}
```

Comment: Try to provide complete example. E.g. showing us, what is the content of your `letters` variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Very good. Ideal example is just short piece of code, which can be taken and run and it shows the problem. Your description is getting close to that ideal, but not yet there. See the "show us how you have created the dict" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values in the `letters` dictionary is a same dictionary; so changing in one value also affects other.

```
def initilize_dict():
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        letters[letter] = data  # <--- referencing the same dictionary
```

Use separated dictionary objects to avoid it.

Comment: And how can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, To answer that, I need to know how `data` is made.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, Simplest way to do it is: Replace `letters[letter] = data` with `letters[letter] = data.copy()` so that separated copy of the dictionaries are assigned.

Comment: data is just initialized once before calling the function

Comment: This works but the lists in data[next] still appear to reference the same list. is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, You can use `copy.deepcopy`: `letters[letter] = copy.copy(data)`   Or, specify the dictionary literal in that statement: `letters[letter] = {....}`